# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'id' error

Tags: junit, code-coverage

```
 @RequestMapping(value= "/project/{id}", method= RequestMethod.GET)
        public Project getEmployeeById(@PathVariable int projectId) throws Exception {

     Optional<Project> emp =  projectservice.getProjectById(projectId);

            if(!emp.isPresent())
                throw new Exception("Could not find employee with id- " + projectId);

            return emp.get();
        }
```

for this test method is:

```
    @Test
    public void getEmployeeByIdtest() throws Exception {

        MockHttpServletResponse response = mvc.perform(get(restEndPoints.GET_EMPLOYEE_ID.uri())
                .param("projectId", "2")).andReturn().getResponse();
        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
        assertNotNull(response.getContentAsString());
    }
```

Getting error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'id'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/project/{id}"
```

you should use

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/project/{projectId}"
```

Name in curlies must match method parameter name.

Comment: I need to write test cases actually?is it correct whatever is mentioned above?@tkruse

Comment: I think having tests is useful, else you get the same error later after starting the application.